# Appending to an array in an object from a ViewController

Tags: objective-c, object

I would like to append an object to an NSMutableArray in an object class from a ViewController. It's set up like bellow, but the code below does not seem to work. If I log the array from the ViewController, it appears to be appended, but if I log it from the object class, it's empty.

**CaptureManager.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AVCamRecorder;
@protocol CaptureManagerDelegate;

@interface CaptureManager : NSObject {
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *assets;

@end
```

**ViewController**

```
CaptureManager *cm = [[CaptureManager alloc] init];
cm.assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[cm.assets addObject:asset];
```

Comment: As you are creating instance in `ViewController` all the data would be binded to that object only, if you want to access info within it you need to do it using `<objectname.attribute> (cm.assest)` only.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your view controller you're creating a new object of `CaptureManager`. So you must pass a pointer of already created `CaptureManager` and use that, or have a shared instance (singleton) and use that in your view controllers, e.g.

```
@interface CaptureManager : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedManager;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *assets;

@end

//--

@implementation
+ (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    static id instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [self new];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (id)init
{  
    self = [super init];
    self.assets = [NSMutableArray new];
    return self;
}
```

Then, in your vc:

```
[[CaptureManager sharedManager].assets addObject:asset];
```

Comment: here OP would not be able to create other object of `CaptureManager` as you have created singleton of it.

Comment: but why you need to create other object of CaptureManager?

Comment: @arturdev i dont know why OP needs it, i just shared info with you :)

Comment: @SpaceShroomies are you sure, that you have logged this `[CaptureManager sharedManager].assets`?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I don't understand you and reason of downvote

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just pass in a specific instance of `CaptureManager` to the VC, either through an initializer or by creating a `CaptureManager` property on the VC and setting it to the specific instance of `CaptureManager`.

You can (and should) read all about why you should avoid [singleton abuse](http://www.objc.io/issue-13/singletons.html) here.